# How to show only three lines (not more than three lines) of a paragraph using CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I want to display only three lines of a paragraph using CSS?

```
<p> This is a long paragraph in HTML which you have in your web page but you can see only 3 lines of it. </p>
```

Note: I could use a div with "overflow:hidden" and set its height to certain pixels until only three lines of

are visible, but I want to know if there is any better way using CSS property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know `line-height` of paragraph, you can set `max-height` equals `line-height * number-of-lines`.

```
p {
  line-height: 18px;
  max-height: 54px; /* line-height * 3 */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `em` in place of `px` in order to make it more adaptive on zoom and custom settings:

```
line-height: 1em;
max-height: 3em;
```